# dante-sever fail to bind ip by interface name in docker container

Tags: bind, docker

I try the docker recently, but the dante-server seem not to work.

#### Environment

os: gentoo x86_64
docker version:

```
Client version: 1.1.0
Client API version: 1.13
Go version (client): go1.3
Git commit (client): 79812e3
Server version: 1.1.0
Server API version: 1.13
Go version (server): go1.3
Git commit (server): 79812000
```

#### DockerFile for customized image

```
From centos:centos6

RUN yum install -y curl

RUN rpm -Uvh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
RUN rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
RUN rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt


RUN echo -e "[nginx]\nname=nginx repo\nbaseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/\$basearch/\ngpgcheck=0\nenabled=1" > /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo

RUN yum install -y nginx tinyproxy dante-server mysql-server
```

#### start container

```
sudo docker run -i \
  --name="proxy" \
  -p 14000:3128 \
  -p 14001:4655 \
  -v ${confdir}/tinyproxy.conf:/etc/tinyproxy.conf \
  -v ${confdir}/dante-server.conf:/etc/sockd.conf \
  -v ${dantelogdir}:/var/log/socks \
  -v ${tinylogdir}:/var/log/tinyproxy \
  devel/centos6 /bin/bash -c "tinyproxy -c /etc/tinyproxy.conf;sockd -f /etc/sockd.conf"
```

#### sockd configuration

```
internal: eth0 port = 4655
external: eth0

logoutput: /var/log/socks/sockd.log
socksmethod: none

user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: root
user.libwrap: root

client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    clientmethod: none # match all idented users that also are in passwordfile
}

socks pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
  socksmethod: none
}
```

The tinyproxy works well when i test it alone. The dante-server passes the configuration test, but log follow errors during the initiation:

> Aug 10 07:54:35 (1407653675.105641) sockd[12]: warning:
>   bindinternal(): bind of address fe80::dc6f:d7ff:fe8f:fa59.46 55
>   (address #2/2) for server to listen on failed: Cannot assign requested
>   address                                   Aug 10 07:54:35
>   (1407653675.105650) sockd[12]: error: serverinit(): failed to bind
>   internal addresses: Cannot assign  requested address
>   Aug 10 07:54:35 (1407653675.105672) sockd[12]: alert: mother[1/1]:
>   shutting down

The erros seems that dante-server can not bind to the ip resolved by the interface name **eth0*. Any help?

Comment: Do you have this issue only at boot and when you run `docker run ...` manually it works?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of «internal: eth0 port = 4655» use «internal: 0.0.0.0 port = 4655»

Comment: Please format your answer to make it more readable (Bold, italic, list , code indentation etc)

Comment: Had the same issue on Debian 12, this did the trick. 

Answer (score 1):

I have been running into the same problem. It seems like there is a >1sec delay in eth0 being set up when a container starts.
What I have done is add a sleep to the entrypoint / run like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT sleep 2 && sockd
```

It seems to solve all the problems I have been having.